# Excel sum amounts if date falls within a specific month

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a formula (not pivot) in excel to do the following:

Check what payments were made within a given month (say in this case, January) and then total up the amounts which are under type A. Here is a data example:

```
| Date       | Amount | Type |
|------------|--------|------|
| 01/01/2015 |    £10 | A    |
| 05/03/2015 |    £20 | B    |
| 17/01/2015 |     £5 | A    |
| 07/01/2015 |    £25 | B    |
```

Here is the closest I have been able to get/find:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A10,"MONTH(A1:A10)=1",B1:B10)
```

The expected output should be: £15 - however I just get 0

Can anyone tell me if this is even possible without having to resort to pivot tables or VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try providing a start and stop date to the [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5).

```
=sumifs(B:B, C:C, "A", A:A, ">="&date(2015, 1, 1), A:A, "<"&date(2015, 2, 1))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I couldn't get your equation working, I might well be doing something wrong. I got as far as this code which works: ```=SUMIFS(B2:B9, C2:C9, "A")``` and just need to add the date check in, with this code which also seems to work: ```=MONTH(B10)&YEAR(B10)=MONTH(A2)&YEAR(A2)```

Comment: Ah forget me! Your code does seem to work, I must have set it up wrong before